# Firebase Facebook log in FIRUserInfo

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, firebase, firebase-authentication

The Code Below Is Not Working At:

```
if let rawProfile = user?.providerData["cachedUserProfile"] as? ......
```

> Error: Cannot subscript a value of type '[FIRUserInfo]' with an index of type 'String'

I've been working on updating my project from the old Firebase console/documentation to the new one.

However it seems that the new one only allows certain things to be pulled when a user signs up, FIRUserInfo, such as displayName, photoURL, and email.

Any idea how i would be able to pull the things i used to such as gender?

List item

```
    static func createUser(viewController: UIViewController, completion: (success: Bool) -> Void) {
    let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
    let facebookLogin = FBSDKLoginManager()

    facebookLogin.logInWithReadPermissions(["public_profile", "email", "user_friends"], fromViewController: viewController, handler: {(facebookResult, facebookError) -> Void in
        if facebookError != nil {
            print("Facebook login failed. Error \(facebookError)")
            completion(success: false)
        } else if facebookResult.isCancelled {
            print("Facebook login was cancelled.")
            completion(success: false)
        } else {
            let credential = FIRFacebookAuthProvider.credentialWithAccessToken(FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken().tokenString)

            FIRAuth.auth()?.signInWithCredential(credential, completion: { (user, error) in
                if error != nil {
                    print("Login failed. \(error)")
                    completion(success: false)
                } else {
                    if let rawProfile = user?.providerData["cachedUserProfile"] as? [String: AnyObject] {
                        guard let firstName = rawProfile["first_name"] as? String else { return }
                        guard let gender = rawProfile["gender"] as? String else { return }
                        guard let uid = rawProfile["id"] as? String else { return }
                        guard let picture = rawProfile["picture"] as? [String : AnyObject] else { return }
                        guard let data = picture["data"] as? [String : AnyObject] else { return }
                        guard let url = data["url"] as? String else { print("failed in data") ; return }

                        let email = user?.providerData["email"] as! NSString as String

                        let newUser = User(firstName: firstName, gender: gender, email: email, imageURL: url)

                        FirebaseController.base.child("users").child(uid).updateChildValues(newUser.jsonValue)

                        self.currentUserID = uid
```

**EDIT**
getting closer and being able to pull the data i need but not creating the user...

```
    static func createUser(viewController: UIViewController, completion: (success: Bool) -> Void) {
    let facebookLogin = FBSDKLoginManager()

    facebookLogin.logInWithReadPermissions(["public_profile", "email", "user_friends"], fromViewController: viewController, handler: {(facebookResult, facebookError) -> Void in
        if facebookError != nil {
            print("Facebook login failed. Error \(facebookError)")
            completion(success: false)
        } else if facebookResult.isCancelled {
            print("Facebook login was cancelled.")
            completion(success: false)
        } else {
            let credential = FIRFacebookAuthProvider.credentialWithAccessToken(FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken().tokenString)

            FIRAuth.auth()?.signInWithCredential(credential, completion: { (user, error) in
                if error != nil {
                    print("Login failed. \(error)")
                    completion(success: false)
                } else {
                    let userDetails = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: ["fields": "id, first_name, email, gender, picture"])

                    userDetails.startWithCompletionHandler({ (connection, result, error) in
                        if error != nil {
                            print("Error connecting FBSDKGraphRequest")
                        } else if let result = result {
                            guard let firstName = result["first_name"] as? String else {return}
                            guard let gender = result["gender"] as? String else {return}
                            guard let uid = result["id"] as? String else {return}
                            guard let imageURL = result["url"] as? String else {return}
                            guard let email = result["email"] as? String else {return}

                            let newUser = User(firstName: firstName, gender: gender, email: email, imageURL: imageURL)

                            FirebaseController.base.child("users").child(uid).updateChildValues(newUser.jsonValue)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a couple hours of searching, reading, and upgrading to the latest Cocoapods, I solved the problem.

It was a mix of Info.plist settings, json parsing, and a few other things.